# Can I customize the auto email for event registration?

Tags: civievent, civimail, message-templates

Can I customize the auto response message for event registration?  Below is a test event I set up and registered for and what was sent, along with a .PDF attachment.

The message is what I'm wanting to make pretty, but I can't find it.  I do see all the other message templates, just not this one.  Kind regards.

[image: auto-response]

Comment: Are you using the Civi Volunteer extension to register volunteers, or are you 'event participants' the volunteers?

Comment: I am using CiviVolunteer.  I create the event, then navigate to my own contact page where I "add event registration."  And my question should probably be "event" registration, not volunteer.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Registering people manually like in your comment will utilize the "Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (off-line)" template.

If people self register online, it will use the "Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line)" template.

For reference, the templates are listed and available to edit from this screen:

> Administer > Communications > Message Templates > "System Workflow
>   Messages" tab